# Is there anyway to implement Card with 2 countries flags and some text I am using react-native-element library with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am using Expo with react-native-element I want to implement a country flag on the left side and right side and text between them in the Card component but I can't find the way something like in the pic.

[country1 vs matchtime & date country2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y3L1.png)

Comment: If you need any more help please let me know and I'll edit my answer to address your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you should use flexbox and styling to get the components to be positioned like you want.

The most important part is to understand how the flexbox layout works and how it divides the screen. Look into it and try to understand how `flexDirection` should be used.

Here's an [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/H1sMWSlS4) with an example of how you can achieve the result you want, it should look something like this:

[image: Example end product]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help actually I am using Card component react-native-element lib https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html I want to implement 2 countries flags date and time in a Card component something like this https://www.google.com/search?q=icc&rlz=1C5CHFA_enPK667PK667&oq=icc&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59l3j0.1305j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8